# How to set time zone to UTC for Cypress tests on windows?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, cypress

I'm trying to run cypress tests on my local windows machine with UTC Time zone. I have added set TZ=UTC for the cypress test run command in package.json, but that doesn't seem to work. I know there are other questions related to this question but I can't find any solid answer. Is any one facing this similar issue?

Code in package.json:
"cypress:run-windows": "SET TZ=UTC& cypress run"

Thanks,

Comment: can you post in the question that you wrote in your `package.json`